# Change programmatically IID_IHTMLInputFileElement value

Tags: javascript, html, c++, visual-c++, mfc

I tried for several days to programmatically put a file path into a input type file element into a CHtmlView control (IE). I have tried this:

```
IHTMLInputFileElement* pInputElem = NULL;
hr = pElemDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLInputFileElement, (void**)&pInputElem);
CString sFile(_T("C:\\Flaviu\\SomeFile.txt"));
BSTR bstrFilesAttribute = sFile.AllocSysString();
hr = pInputElem->put_value(bstrFilesAttribute); // hr is S_OK though
SysFreeString(bstrFilesAttribute);
```

but didn't work, I mean there is no SomeFile.txt chosen on input file.

I have read on several sites that I cannot edit or set value on an input type file element for security reason.

Somewhere, someone, suggested a simple solution: to make a copy of the original web page, and edit html source code and replace input type file element to an input type text. Which I have done. I only have to solve "action" attribute on form:

Original html source code:

```
<form name="uf" method="POST" action="/WS6ERT/SomeFile.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="background-color: #c6c6c6; padding: 5px">
    <span>Choose file:</span> <span> <input type="file" name="linkdoc" size="75" value=""></span><span><input type="submit" value="Send"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

and I made a copy, and I replaced input type file, with input type text:

```
<form name="uf" method="POST" 
action="https://originalsite.com/WS6ERT/SomeFile.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="background-color: #c6c6c6; padding: 5px">
    <span>Choose file::</span> <span> <input type="text" name="linkdoc"> 
</span><span><input type="submit" value="Send"></span>
</form>
```

The important tags attribute: "**action=**"
Of course that is not correct what I have written in my html source, because my path is pointing on the original file, which I didn't edit...

Is there a way to solve this issue? To put programmatically a file path into an input type file on a CHtmlView view? Or how to overcome this problem?

**Last Edit:** Can I setup the file with javascript ? I saw here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-files that is possible to setup a file in **files** attribute. But I don't know how to do that ...

Comment: `CHtmlView` has `Navigate2` method, it should work fine for setting the web page, or changing existing page and forcing page update. Please show MCVE

Comment: What is mean "MCVE" ? :)

Comment: "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, I will come back with a sample code (and project I hope)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handle to `CHtmlView*` then use `CHtmlView::Navigate2` or `CHtmlView::Navigate`

This should do the job unless html control is busy with a previous request, for example you already made a `Navigate` request and the html control is not finished processing that request. In the case, you can override `CHtmlView::OnNavigateComplete2`, which lets you know the html control is finished with the previous navigation request, and it can receive a new request. Alternatively you could use a wait function to wait for the control to finish using the `for` loop shown below.

```
CString filename = _T("C:\\Test\\test.html");
CStringW content = LR"(<html><body>  content  </body></html>)";

//optional: in case the control is busy with previous request
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    MSG msg;
    while(::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) 
        if(!AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage())
            break;
    CFile test;
    if(test.Open(filename, CFile::modeNoTruncate | CFile::modeWrite))
        break;
}

CFile fout;
if(fout.Open(filename, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
{
    content = LR"(<html><body>  content UPDATE </body></html>)";
    CStringA utf8 = CW2A(content, CP_UTF8);
    fout.Write(utf8, utf8.GetLength());
    fout.Close();
    htmlview->Navigate(filename, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Yes, your example show me how to navigate to a page ... which is done now ... the problem here is that I cannot setup a file on an input type file html tag ... programmatically ... that is my issue.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. If you want to change `<form>` it would be easier to if it starts with `<form id = "uf" ...>`, instead of `name=uf` because name returns a collection.